# django filenames suffixed with asterisk

Tags: django, python-2.7

I installed Django on Ubuntu 11.10 by doing the following:

```
wget https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.4.1/tarball/
tar xzvf index.html
cd Django-1.4.1
sudo python setup.py install
```

Some python files are suffixed with an *. For example:

```
django-admin.py*
daily_cleanup.py*
manage.py*
```

What is the significance of the asterisk?

Comment: Should probably ask this on another one of the stack exchange forums since its not really a programming question. http://askubuntu.com/ for ubuntu questions, or google would probably have found it just as quickly without bothering anyone here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asterik signifies that files have `executable` bit set, so you can run them as `./filename.py`. It's just output formatting of `ls` command with `-F` flag set to default.

If you run `ls` with full path, bypassing aliases, like `/bin/ls`, you will probably see those disappear along with coloured output.